# Socket.sendall() not sending to all connected clients

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm struggling with the .sendall() method for a client/server -setup. Several clients can connect individually and send messages to the server and get the echoed response. However, I expect the messages sent to show up for all the connected clients in a chat-like Environment.

This is the code running on the server application.

```
def clientHandler(conn, addr):
    name = addr[0]
    print(addr, " connected to the server")
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if tostr(data)[0:5] == '/name':
            print('setting name')
            setname(data)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(str.encode(checkname(addr[0]) + tostr(data)))
        print('Received Message: ', tostr(data))


HOST = '' #LOCALHOST
PORT = 1400

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
sock.listen(999999)

print('Server is running' + '-'*10)

for i in range(999999):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    Thread(target = clientHandler, args = (conn, addr)).start()

sock.close()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're very confused. A TCP socket connection is between exactly two endpoints. (E.g. one client and one server).

Comment: Oh, well is there any way to echo the data to all connections, or would I have to use some sort of global buffer for all threads to read from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had originally said in a comment (but now decided is better said in an answer), `sendall` sends all bytes to a **single** connection.  You need to add something like:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
all_clients = []
```

at the top; in the main loop, where you now have just `conn, addr = sock.accept()`, have

```
conn, addr = sock.accept()
with lock:
    all_clients.append(conn)
```

In `clientHandler`, where you now have just `conn.sendall(str.encode(checkname(addr[0]) + tostr(data)))`, have instead

```
with lock:
    for c in all_clients:
        c.sendall(str.encode(checkname(addr[0]) + tostr(data)))
```

IOW, you need to explicitly code the "broadcast" business logic in your server -- it's absolutely not implicit in `sendall` (whose semantics you may have misunderstood).

Comment: Okay I see. Thank you for elaborating your previous reply. Indeed I have misunderstood sendall. So I've understood the above solution as such, that I must save all connections and then iterate over the list of connections with sendall to echo all incoming data to all connections.

Comment: Until you find one of the clients blocked with a window size of 0, yes:)

Comment: @MartinJames, the `all_clients` list should indeed be maintained to shunt aside clients with problems (including simply the client having terminated and closed its socket!), including time-outs!, to make this much more robust, but that's far from a trivial refactoring problem:-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli Yes, I know.  Just Christmas trolling:)